# Get text box with textfields on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm coding a page with some radio buttons and stuck with some problems. Here is my 
current output

[image]

Below is my code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        #sitehtn {
            display: none
        }

        .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 600px;
            background-color: rgb(179, 174, 174);
        }
        #datepickerT {
            margin-left: 2em;
        }
        .eventDateDiv {
            height: 150px;
            width: 30%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        #daysBetween {
            margin-top: -1.4em;
            margin-left: 30%;
        }
        .eventShowDiv {
            height: 250px;
            width: 30%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        .event {
            color: green;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepickerF" ).datepicker({
                      showOn : "button",
                 buttonImage : "calendar.gif",
             buttonImageOnly : true
            });

            $( "#datepickerT" ).datepicker({
                      showOn : "button",
                 buttonImage : "calendar.gif",
             buttonImageOnly : true
            });

            $('#getdays').click(function() {
                var start = $('#datepickerF').datepicker('getDate');
                var end   = $('#datepickerT').datepicker('getDate');
                var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
                document.getElementById("daysBetween").innerText=days;
            });

            $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
                $('#sitehtn').hide()
                $(this).parent().next().show()
            });

            function displayResult(browser) {
                document.getElementById("result").value=browser
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="eventDateDiv">
            <div class="event">
                EVENT DATE
            </div>
            <p>FROM: <input type="text" id="datepickerF" /></p>
            <p>To: <input type="text" id="datepickerT" /></p>
            <button id="getdays">NO.OF DAYS </button>
            <p id="daysBetween"> </p>
        </div> 
        <div class="eventShowDiv">
            <div class="event">
                EVENT SHOW TIME
            </div>
            <p>TYPE OF SHOW: </p>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sitewebGroup" value="Courtier" id="courtierRadio" />
                Unique
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="site" id="sitehtn" />
            <br />
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sitewebGroup" value="Agence" id="agenceRadio" />
                Varied
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="textfield3" id="sitehtn" />
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

My actual expected output is.

1. When I click on Unique radioButton, A textbox will appear and automatically Next 
   Radio Button(Varied)will hide
2. The Text Box include..Four Text Fields Inside it..two fields For The FROM and
   TO Date picker and a Content Placeholder,and Last a Button To add same 4
   Fields to the next Line in the same Text Box

As I'm new in this field, I need your support and valuable comments to solve this.

Comment: where are the HTML part?

Comment: @SunilKumar:sorry nw i re edit my code..check it

Comment: For #2

You mean the `textbox` near the `unique` radio button should have the values of FROM TO

Comment: The `id` must be unique, `<input type="text" name="site" id="sitehtn" />`and `<input type="text" name="textfield3" id="sitehtn" />`have the same id, you can change id or use class instead. With class `$('.sitehtn').hide();` works.

Comment: @AlexBall:Thanks i correct it..but how i can hide the next radio button when i select the first

Comment: @user2503857 if you want hide the second radio button when you check the first you could try this (using class): `$('input[type=radio]').change(function(e) { if(e.target.id == 'courtierRadio') $('#agenceRadio').parent().hide(); $('.sitehtn').hide(); $(this).parent().next().show(); });`. This is an example but could be better.

Answer (score 1):

This may work with the date picker. You have to add the content holder and textbox though.

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <style>
            #sitehtn {
                display: none
            }

            .container {
                width: 100%;
                height: 600px;
                background-color: rgb(179, 174, 174);
            }
            #datepickerT {
                margin-left: 2em;
            }
            .eventDateDiv {
                height: 150px;
                width: 400px;
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
            #daysBetween {
                margin-top: -1.4em;
                margin-left: 30%;
            }
            .eventShowDiv {
                height: 250px;
                width: 30%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
            .event {
                color: green;
                margin-top: 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
        function loading() {
                $( ".datepickerF" ).datepicker({
                          showOn : "button",
                     buttonImage : "calendar.gif",
                 buttonImageOnly : true
                });

                $( ".datepickerT" ).datepicker({
                          showOn : "button",
                     buttonImage : "calendar.gif",
                 buttonImageOnly : true
                });

                $('.getdays').click(function() {
                    var start = $(this).prev().prev().find('input').datepicker('getDate');
                    var end   = $(this).prev().find('input').datepicker('getDate');
                    var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
                    $(this).next().text(days);
                });

                $('input[id=courtierRadio]').change(function() {
                    $('#hideRadio').html("");
                    $('#hideRadio').append(getAppleInfo());
                });
                function displayResult(browser) {
                    document.getElementById("result").value=browser
                }
            };
            window.onload = loading;

        // anti-pattern! keep reading...
        function getAppleInfo() {
            var eventDateDiv ="";
            eventDateDiv = $("<div></div>").addClass("eventDateDiv");
            eventDateDiv.append($("<p></p>").text("FROM: ").append($("<input>").attr("class", "datepickerF").attr("type", "text")));
            eventDateDiv.append($("<p></p>").text("TO: ").append($("<input>").attr("class", "datepickerT").attr("type", "text")));
            eventDateDiv.append($("<button></button>").text("NO.OF DAYS ").attr("class", "getdays"));
            eventDateDiv.append($("<p></p>").attr("class", "daysBetween"));
            eventDateDiv.append($("<a>").text("Add Another").attr("href", "#").attr("onclick", "belowDiv(this)"));
            return eventDateDiv;

        }
        function belowDiv(self){
            $('#hideRadio').append(getAppleInfo());
            loading();
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="eventDateDiv" title="numb">
                <div class="event">
                    EVENT DATE
                </div>
                <p>FROM: <input type="text" class="datepickerF" /></p>
                <p>To: <input type="text" class="datepickerT" /></p>
                <button class="getdays">NO.OF DAYS </button>
                <p class="daysBetween"> </p>
            </div> 
            <div class="eventShowDiv" title="dumb">
                <div class="event">
                    EVENT SHOW TIME
                </div>
                <p>TYPE OF SHOW: </p>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sitewebGroup" value="Courtier" id="courtierRadio" />
                    Unique
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="site"  />
                <br />
                <div id="hideRadio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sitewebGroup" value="Agence" id="agenceRadio" />
                    Varied
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="textfield3" />
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your #1 question try this.

```
$('#courtierRadio').on('change', function () {
   $('#sitehtn').show();
   $('#agenceRadio').hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your code it works but i have one more dobut what changes in the below code i do to dispaly all my textfiels beside my first radio button now itz shows only one textbox..if i add more it not displaying

Comment: $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
                $('#sitehtn').hide()
                $(this).parent().next().show()
            }); //this is ma code